# LongListSelector Jump-List in C# (Windows Universal Platform Apps - Windows 10 Development)

Tags: windows, grid, selector, jump-list

When I was coding for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 I used a LongListSelector to create a jump-list menu that looked a little like this:

[Jump-list in Windows Phone 8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADDjH.png)

However, I have since started to code Windows Universal Platform apps instead for Windows 10 and since upgrading my phone from 8.1 to 10, I see that these menus now look like this:

[Jump-list in Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIhC5.png)

I'm wondering how I can create this using C# in a Windows Universal Platform app. I have over 100 items which the user can select from and this is a really nice way of quickly finding an item to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you described is now built-in SemanticZoom control. [This article](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx) will help you implement it with code sample.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give it a go! Cheers!